# Add Vertical Line and Align Icons using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a vertical line between the orange icons and text fields and then also fix placement of the "OR" text and align the icons properly, as shown in the image below. What updates can I make to my code to do that?

**What I would like**

[image]

**What I have right now**

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body{
width:1000px;
font-family:verdana;
}

input{
position:relative;
left:143px;
width:70%;
height:50px;
padding:10px;
}

textarea{
position:relative;
left:68px;
width:70%;
height:150px;
}

.label{
display:inline;
width:140px;
}

.icon{
float:left;
}

.divitem{
padding:10px;
padding-left:20px;
background-color:#BFD6F6;
border-top:1px solid #7C94A0;;
border-bottom:1px solid #7C94A0;;
}

.field{
background-color:#C6DEFF;
border:1px solid #7C94A0;
}

#sub{
width:80px;
height:40px;
left:0px;
border:1px solid #7C94A0;
border-radius:5px;
}

#mail{
left:149px;
}

#phone{
left:139px;
}

#name{
width:1024px;
height:100px;
}

#cntct{
width:1024px;
}

#desc{
width:1024px;
border-style:none;
}

#dlabel{
vertical-align:top;
}

</style>
<title>E-mail US</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>E-mail Us</h1>
<form action="confirmed.php" method="get">

<div class="divitem" id="name">

    <h2 class="label">Name</h2>
    <input class="field" type="text"/>
    <img width="40" class="icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png">

</div>

<div class="divitem" id="desc">
    <img width="40" class="icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png">
    <h2 id="dlabel" class="label">Description</h2>
    <textarea class="field"></textarea>


</div>

<div class="divitem" id="cntct">
<img width="40" class="icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png">
    <h2 class="label">Email</h2>
    <input id="mail" class="field" type="text"/>

    <br/><span id="or">Or</span><br/>
    <img width="40" class="icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png">
    <h2 class="label">Phone</h2>
    <input id="phone" class="field" type="text"/>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input id="sub" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="confirmed.php" method="get">
    <div class="divitem" id="name">
        <div class="icon">
            <img width="40" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="label">
             <h2>Name</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divitem" id="desc">
        <div class="icon">
            <img width="40" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="label">
             <h2 id="dlabel">Description</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <textarea class="field"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divitemcntct" id="cntct">
        <div class="icon">
            <img width="40" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="label">
             <h2>Email</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input id="mail" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div><span id="or">Or</span>

    <div class="divitemPhone" id="Phone">
        <div class="icon">
            <img width="40" src="http://i.imgur.com/zZE0y3y.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="label">
             <h2>Phone</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input id="phone" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divitem" id="desc">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input id="sub" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.divitem {
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-color:#BFD6F6;
    border-top:1px solid #7C94A0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #7C94A0;
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
}
.label {
    display:inline;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
.icon {
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
}
input, textarea {
    position:relative;
    left:143px;
    width:60%;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#C6DEFF;
    border:1px solid #7C94A0;
}
#or {
    text-align:center;
    width:1000px;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#BFD6F6;
}
#sub {
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    left:0px;
    border:1px solid #7C94A0;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#E6E6E6;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.divitemcntct
{
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-color:#BFD6F6;
    border-top:1px solid #7C94A0;
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
}
.divitemPhone
{
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-color:#BFD6F6;
    border-bottom:1px solid #7C94A0;
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5cW/49/)

[image]

Comment: thank you, but this looks a bit different then what I need. respectfully, the vertical lines and question mark icons are aligned incorrectly from what I need: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnou1.jpg

Comment: with a short period of time i did this..! Give me some time will post the answer

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it. I look forward to your updated answer!